# Consequences of poor performance early in the campaign

Tags: warhammer-40k-dawn-of-war-ii

In vanilla DoW2's campaign, does wasting time before the Tyranids show up have any consequences?

A friend and I have been playing vanilla DoW 2's coop campaign mode. However, we screwed up in pretty much the biggest way possible - not only did we fail to snag any bonus deployments, we also failed one of the missions by misunderstanding the objective. All of this wasted us a few campaign days; we could've accomplished what we did much faster.

Both of us rushed through the campaign back when the game first came out; I remember that wasting time like this was punished by an ever-increasing amount of Tyranid infestation (not that I remember what the consequences of THAT were). Problem is, we haven't encountered the Tyranids yet; we are wondering, do lost and/or failed deployments even matter, when the infestation sliders aren't even in play yet? Assuming we had failed one and the same mission a hundred times in a row, what would be different to a campaign where everything has been done perfectly (aside from the fact that the team failing a hundred times would have a ton of experience on their squads from whatever kills they racked up), assuming those failures happened before the Tyranids show up?

Comment: Some buildings which you can capture, can be lost forever, since there are missions for which you can only participate once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Failing missions before the Tyranids show up does not increase the infestation level. Further, there aren't any achievements that are indirectly made impossible or harder by failing missions at this point. The obvious question - "Will my score be hurt?" also gets a favorable answer - no. The easiest and most likely way to obtain a high score (and the related achievement) is to keep repeating the endless optional and defense missions once all squads are at level 20 and the final mission is available - early failures will not be a detriment to this approach.

Further, Tyranid infestation doesn't actually **do** much, so failing after the 'nids show up isn't too bad either - even if all three planets were to become maximally infested, the only thing that would change is some of the ending text, and *arguably* the amount of Tyranid buildings encountered while deploying on the infested planets.

Answer (score 0):

To add more details to the [other answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/98033/226066), Tyranid infestation increases the amount of points you lose per deployment day. The effect is lessened if you are able to deploy more than once per day by performing well.

> we are wondering, do lost and/or failed deployments even matter

Depending on how you intend to play the game, it can matter. There are temporary missions which you can complete only as long as it didn't expire yet. Some of them require you to kill a target/boss and remain for 5 days. Some others are defence missions and require you to protect an attacked building and they only remain for 3 days. If a defence mission expires, you lose the building you previously had and might have to capture it again. Since you can get at most 3 deployments per day if you perform really well (and a minimum of 1), it means you take the risk that a mission may expire if you lose too many days.

Now, for the flavours part.

Depending on how infected a planet is, the game will visually reflect it. If the planet is moderately infected, you can see some hive fleet tendrils touching the planet. If the planet is entirely infected, the planet is almost entirely covered by the hive fleet. And if the planet is (almost) free of infection, it will appear as clean as when you just started the game.

This will also be reflected on the map of the star system (the one you use to travel between planets).

Other than that, I haven't noticed any difference to the missions when playing a fully infested game nor a fully clean game. Perhaps the map looked more green, as if there was gas floating in the air, although that's just more graphical flavour.

Depending on your final grade (which depends on your score), you get either of the 3 endings. The video doesn't change, but the text (which tells the story) does, if that matters to you.

In the best ending, Gabriel gives a speech about how the Emperor saw the day the world would need heroes such as you (the player) to fight back and save the subsector.

In the moderate ending, I think Gabriel says something about the hive fleet being defeated and pushed out of the Blood Ravens' recruiting world, saving the chapter from being destroyed.

In the worst ending, although the hive fleet was destroyed, Gabriel's speech and the post-ending flavour text are very grim. They mention the fact some of the tendrils will manage to escape and regrow into a fully grown hive fleet by feeding on nearby planets/star systems, and although the Blood Ravens' recruiting world was saved this day, it will keep being plagued by the Great Devourer for many centuries to come.

However, unless you planned it in advance, the worst ending is harder to get than the best ending, because you are gaining a lot more points than you can possibly lose if you play properly. You can see what are the different ways to gain/lose points by hovering your mouse over the top panel during a campaign. Some ways to lose points include letting missions expire. I think it was -30 points for a defence mission and -100 for a boss mission, and -10 points per level of infestation on all 3 planets combined.